# C# - Monogame - Program still uses an image after setting it to null

Tags: c#, monogame

Okay so basically I want to load an image (check), use it (check), unload it(semi-check) and then load it again (fail)...

So here is what I did:

```
TileTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, new System.IO.FileStream(tileTextureName, System.IO.FileMode.Open));
```

It load a textuure, works fine, I can draw it no problem, then when I don't want to use it I set it to null

```
this.TileTexture = null;
```

and it works fine, image dissapears, **and I am able to load some other image** from anywhere on my computer again (and then that image is put into that Texture2D variable where the previous one was), but when I want to load the image I used before again, even though now another image is stored in that Texture2D variable, I get an exception:

**The program cannot acces the file because it is being used by another process.** (Which would be my program).

How do I then completly stop my Monogame program from using this image so I can acces it again at the same runtime if maybe I would need to ?

Comment: *How do I then completly stop my Monogame program from using this image so I can acces it again*: close your stream when you are done with it

Comment: Thanks, that worked well ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your stream when you are done with it. Instead of this:

```
TileTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, new System.IO.FileStream(tileTextureName, System.IO.FileMode.Open));
```

Try:

```
using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(tileTextureName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    TileTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, fs);
}
```

`using` will take care of closing and disposing the stream

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a new steam on your method call:

```
new System.IO.FileStream(tileTextureName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
```

Instead, place it in a var and then call the .Close method

```
var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(tileTextureName, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
...
stream.Close();
```

Comment: is Close(); enough or do I also need to Dispoe(); ?

Comment: Basically Close() in this case calls the Dispose. But "Best practise" is Disposing with the "using" method like Matt's answer